# [google-fit]; write my blood sugar data to Google Fit, but something went wrong(REQUIRES_APP_WHITELISTING) during the test

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-api

"OAuth 2.0 Client ID" was successfully obtained，but "OAuth consent Scree" was not verified

```html
FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_GLUCOSE,FitnessOptions.ACCESS_WRITE)
                .addDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_GLUCOSE,FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();
DataSource mDataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
                    .setStreamName("test")
                    .setAppPackageName(context)
                    .setDataType(HealthDataTypes.TYPE_BLOOD_GLUCOSE)
                    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
                    .build();
DataPoint bloodGlucose = DataPoint.builder(mDataSource)
                .setField(HealthFields.FIELD_BLOOD_GLUCOSE_LEVEL,15)
                .setTimestamp(now.getTimeMillis(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
DataSet dataSet = DataSet.builder(mDataSource)
                .add(dataPoint)
                .build();
Task<Void> response = Fitness
                .getHistoryClient(context, GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(context, fitnessOptions))
                .insertData(dataSet);
```

I've passed the GoogleSignIn permission and an exception(**com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 5024**) has occurred when inserting data

please see: [https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/write-blood-glucose-data]
Does not allow the user to write blood sugar information anymore? or maybe there's something wrong with my code.

I would be very grateful if you could give us some suggestions based on your rich experience.

Answer (score 2):

May be a little late, but if anyone else runs into this, the following may be of help.

From Google Fit docs:

> Google Fit has health data types for measurements related to managing
> general health (as opposed to fitness). Because health data can be
> sensitive, these data types have sensitive scopes. This means you need
> to apply for OAuth API verification for sensitive scopes on top of the
> standard authorization permissions for Android and REST to read and
> write to these data types.
>
> Google will review your application and grant or deny verification.
> Users will review the scope requests and grant or deny access to
> these.
>
> **Note: Google has temporarily stopped taking new requests to write to health data types. We are updating our policy and process for
> reviewing requests and will update this documentation again when we
> resume.**

As at 1 Jun 2021.

https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/health